# HibernateJpaDialect PersistenceException translation for StaleStateExceptions

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

I didn't understand the implementation of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect` for `translateExceptionIfPossible()` method of the `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` interface. It converts `StaleStateException` or `StaleObjectStateException` to `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`. Since its a JPA dialect shouldn't it be converting them to `JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException`?

While troubleshooting a bug I came across this spring's code base and am curious to know why is it implemented this way.

It would be great if someone can throw some light on this.

Comment: I would file an issue in their JIRA, explaining my concerns. It indeed looks strange to throw hibernate-specific exceptions, and I don't see a reason for it